# Example 4, Sec. 22, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How is this quotient space homeomorphic with $S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Here is Example 4, Sec. 22, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be the closed unit ball
> $$ \left\{ ( x,  y) \lvert \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \ \right\} $$
> in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $X^*$ be the partition of $X$ consisting of all the one-point sets $\{ (x , y ) \}$ for which $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, along with the set $S^1 = \left\{ (x , y) \ \vert \ x^2 + y^2 = 1 \ \right\}$. Typical saturated open sets in $X$ are pictured by the shaded regions in Figure 22.4.  One can show that $X^*$ is homeomorphic with the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ called the *unit-$2$-sphere*, defined by
> $$ S^2 = \left\{ \ (x, y, z) \ \vert \ x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1 \ \right\}. $$

Now my question is, how is the space $X^*$ homeomorphic with the subspace $S^2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I'm sorry but I have not been able to make much sense of Figure 22.4 either; so can someone please also elaborate this to me?

Here are some relevant definitions.

Quotient Map:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces; let $p \colon X \to Y$ be a surjective map. The map $p$ is said to be a *quotient map* provided a subset $U$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.   .  .  .

Saturated Sets:

> We say that a subset $C$ of $X$ is *saturated* (with respect to the surjective map $p \colon X \to Y$) if $C$ contains every set $p^{-1} \left( \ \{ \ y \ \} \ \right)$ that it intersects. Thus $C$ is saturated if it equals the complete inverse image of a subset of $Y$.  .  .  .

Quotient Topology:

> If $X$ is a [topological] space and $A$ is a *set* and if $p \colon X \to A$ is a surjective map, then there exists exactly one topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $A$ relative to which $p$ is a quotient map; it is called the *quotient topology* induced by $p$.
>
> The topology $\mathscr{T}$ is of course defined by letting it consist of those subsets $U$ of $A$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.  . . .

Quotient Space:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $X^*$ be a partition of $X$ into disjoint subsets whose union is $X$. Let $p \colon X \to X^*$ be the surjective map that carries each point of $X$ to the element of $X^*$ containing it. In the quotient topology induced by $p$, the space $X^*$ is called a *quotient space* of $X$.

Finally, here is the image of Page 139 of Munkres. I would appreciate a detailed answer rather than a mere hint.

[image]

Comment: Informally, you're "collapsing" the circle $S^1$ to one point while keeping the other points in the closed unit ball distinct. Let's say that $S^1$ goes to the "north pole" on the sphere. Then a neighborhood of $S^1$ in the closed unit ball (as depicted by $U$ for example) ends up as a neighborhood of the north pole, while $V$, being closer to the center of the unit ball, ends up nearer to the south pole. This isn't explicit or a proof by any means but more of an intuitive explanation.

Comment: Imagine wrapping a circle piece of paper around a ball. The boundary of the circle will be "scrunched" at the north pole of the ball. Identifying the points of the boundary of the circle deals with the "scrunching"

Answer (score 1):

You can brute force this using basic properties of compact spaces vis á vis quotient maps. The map $\varphi:X\to S^2:$

$(x,y)\mapsto \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}x,\frac{1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}y,2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1\right)$

is continuous (even at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, if we define $\varphi$ to be equal to zero there) and surjective. Since $X$ and $S^2$ are compact, $\varphi$ is a quotient map.

Now, $\varphi$ respects the identifications made by the quotient map $p$ that induces $X^*.$ That is, if $\|\vec x\|=1,$ then $\varphi$ sends $\vec x$ to $(0,0,1)$ whereas $\varphi$ is injective on the open unit disk $B(0,1).$ Thus, we get a continuous $\overline \varphi:X^*\to S^2$ that satisfies $\overline \varphi\circ p=\varphi.$ But $p$ also respects the identifications made by $\varphi$ so we get a continuous map going in the other direction $\overline p:X^*\to S^2.$

To finish, show that $\overline p$ and $\overline \varphi$ are inverses.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\bar{\varphi}$ is a homeomorphism? And what is the definition of $\bar{p}$?

Answer (score 0):

We say that $a\sim b$ for $a,b\in X$ iff $a,b$ belong to the same element from the considered partition. Therefore $$a\sim b\iff 
a=b\text{ or }a,b\in S^1.
$$
This is an equivalence relation and $X^*$ is the set of the equivalence classes. Let $p\colon X\to X^*$ be a projection $p(x)=[x]_\sim$.

Let $f\colon X\to S^2$ be 'wrapping a sphere in a unit ball', that is
$$f(r\cos\alpha,r\sin\alpha)=(\sin\beta\cos\alpha,\sin\beta\sin\alpha,\cos\beta),\text{ where }\beta = \pi r$$ ([spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)). Then
$$f(a)=f(b)\iff a=b\text{ or }a,b\in S^1\iff a\sim b.\tag{1}\iff p(a)=p(b).$$
Therefore $f$ can be factorised by $X^*$, that is there exists a unique $f^*\colon X^*\to S^2$ such that $f^*\circ p = f$.

- From (1) we have $f^*$ is injection.
- Since $f$ is onto then $f^*$ is onto.
- Therefore $f^*$ is a bijection. We'll show that $f^*$ is a homeomorphism.

**Fact** $g\colon X^*\to Y$ is continuous iff $g\circ p$ is continuous.

*Proof.* From the very definition of the topology on $X^*$

**Corollary** $f^*$ is continuous.

It remains to show that $f^*$ is open. It's equivalent to show that $f(U)$ is open in $S^2$ for any open and saturated from $X$. Each such set is a sum of some sets from the family
$$\mathcal B=\mathcal B_1\cup\{R_r:0<r<1\}\text{ where } \mathcal B_1=\{U\subset X\setminus S^1:U\text{ is open}\}\\\text{ and }R_r:=\{(x,y):r<x^2+y^2\leq 1\}.$$

- If $U\in\mathcal B$ then the openess of the image $f(U)$ can be shown analysing the derivative $Df$ of $f$.
- The set $f(R_r)=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2: z>\cos(\pi\cdot r)\}$ is open.

Comment: I realised that this is so old question in the last part of writing the answer. I decided to post my answer (to save my work) but I don't understand why this post has appeared in the list of latest questions.

Comment: Offtopic: How does one pronounce your name? (Still working on the answer u gave before btw)

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational, ha ha. This is my name: https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mateusz

Comment: @Mateo How do you conclude that relation: $a \sim b$ iff to $a,b$
  belong to the same element from the considered partition is equivalent to $a=b$ or $a,b \in S^1$?

Comment: @Math23 just because the partition consists of singletons {(x,y)} and a circle.